# Mouse position in Linux kernel

Tags: kernel, mouse

How I can get current mouse position (in coordinates **{x,y}**) in kernel space?

I use the following code, but it returns me **x** and **y** positions as 255.

Here is code:

```
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/jiffies.h> 
#include <linux/types.h> 
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
#include <linux/errno.h>
#include <linux/miscdevice.h>
#include <linux/random.h>
#include <linux/poll.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/spinlock.h>
#define OURMOUSE_MINOR 0 
#define OURMOUSE_BASE 0x300

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

struct file_operations our_mouse_fops = {
};

static struct miscdevice our_mouse = {
OURMOUSE_MINOR,
"ourmouse"
, &our_mouse_fops
};


int init_module(void)
{
misc_register(&our_mouse);

int delta_x = inb(OURMOUSE_BASE);
int delta_y = inb(OURMOUSE_BASE+1);

printk(KERN_INFO "module: position x %d\n", delta_x);
printk(KERN_INFO "module: position y %d\n", delta_y);
return 0;

}
void cleanup_module(void)
{
misc_deregister(&our_mouse);
}
```

Comment: I doubt that it will be possible.  Why do you believe that it is possible?  Do you believe that the mouse knows its position?  I suspect that only the window manager will have this information. … … … Also, wouldn't you expect mouse coordinates to be two-byte quantities?

Comment: This very much looks like an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to achieve (your X) by using a kernel module to read the mouse position (your Y)? In general, mouse movements will be available on the kernel input layer, and other modules can access this layer (as can userspace, via `/dev/eventX`). Also note that they may be many mice or similar devices (touchpads) attached to a single machine, there's no "the mouse". Also note that X (the graphical windows system) adds another translation layer to mouse events.